# List or update outdated Go packages with major version update

Tags: go

With `go get -u` it's possible to update all packages in a Go application that uses go.mod. However, there's a convention in Go that the package name gets updated for a major version when there are breaking changes.

For example "github.com/ahmetb/go-linq" changes in "github.com/ahmetb/go-linq/v2" after an update with breaking changes.

How can I detect if any of the packages I use updated their major version?

Comment: You look at the tags of the repository containing the package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has an [open proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40323) that is on hold.

From that thread you may want to use [gomajor](https://github.com/icholy/gomajor) and see if it works for you.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!